# Get XPATH expression with 2 spans in a div

Tags: xpath, webdriver

```
<div class="grid_12">
<span class="gwt-InlineLabel">What ever</span>
 &nbsp;
(
<span class="gwt-InlineLabel">Endorsement</span> 
&nbsp;-&nbsp;
<span class="gwt-InlineLabel">Draft</span>)
</div>
```

I need an dynamic XPATH expression to assert the text " What ever Endorsement Draft"

Comment: XPath 1.0 or 2.0? Invoked how? Are you saying you want the content of the span elements, separated by spaces, and you want to ignore the text in between the span elements? Is it significant that the "w" of "what ever" gets capitalized?

Comment: Using Xpath2. nothing in the text should change.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `//div[@class='grid_12']//text()`, but if you know the depth of the `div`, you can avoid using the first `//`.

Comment: The problem could be your `&nbsp;` Retry evaluating XPath by removing them. It should work.

Comment: That expression will return a sequence of text nodes. In some contexts, the processor might only use the first of the returned text nodes.

Comment: What I am trying to do is get an Xpath expression which I can use in Slenium WebDriver to get the actual text content something like XpathExpression.getText(); and it should return "what ever Endorsement Draft"

Answer (score 0):

[Answer of Daniel Haley](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6740956/841064) suggests to use `//div[@class='grid_12']//text()` but it will match `&nbsp;` too.

A better idea is to returns texts of spans only:

```
//div[@class='grid_12']/span/text()
```

(that will return `["what ever", "Endorsement", "Draft"]`) and then concat them.